# changing the html DOM via javascript not responding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am changing the background of a div with a function. The following is my html code:

```
$scope.Background = 'img/seg5en.png';
document.getElementById("Bstyle").style.background = "url("+$scope.Background+") no-repeat center fixed;";           
console.log(document.getElementById("Bstyle").style.background);
console.log("url("+$scope.Background+") no-repeat center fixed;");
```

Originally, `$scope.Background` is equal to "`img/bg.png`" which is specified on top of my document. 
The first console.log prints that the value of style.background as "`img/bg.png`".

However, the second `console.log` prints: `url(img/seg5en.png) no-repeat center fixed`.

I do not understand why my html page does not update though.

Comment: some browser do not support background; will you try by using backgroundImage

Comment: @AshokShah Which browsers are you referring to? Mosaique? Lynx? Can you provide where your information can be researched?

Comment: `img/bg.png` would not make sense in a `elem.style.background` property - you need to at least wrap that value in `url()`.

Comment: when you inspect the property via dev tools does it have the new value? Does the user call your function by button click or on page load ?

Comment: @Searching yes console.log($scope.Background ) gives me the new value. The user calls by button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change DOM using angularised way

Use ng-style to change style of element from JavaScript.

In angular you can assign value to $scope variable and it can be access to your view.

Here is demo for resolve your issue

```js
function ChangeBackground($scope) {   
    
   $scope.Background = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdNIsxlrqB0Bqy-qmamo6tt9fdqqL9p43Bf5oy11xt0UuAa9vAILYjMX7_';

  $scope.changeImage = function(){  
      $scope.Background ='https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ2I2AW0JI-scAY0Phe321d1Yi8UHbFhsIk8OXTbpfEfaNf9F4V9lt60rs';
   }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ChangeBackground">
    <div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + Background + ')'}" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porttitor mi non consequat varius. Curabitur libero tellus, placerat in metus nec, porttitor facilisis mi. Vivamus nec mattis felis. Cras mattis in mi sed feugiat. Sed ut hendrerit nisi, at tincidunt nibh. Donec vel malesuada orci. Nunc auctor tortor in mi consectetur gravida. Phasellus eleifend erat lectus, convallis tincidunt nisi euismod et. Donec a ornare eros, et eleifend magna. Phasellus viverra pellentesque metus, in lacinia tortor egestas nec. Suspendisse luctus dolor sit amet nisi interdum, nec commodo orci consectetur. Phasellus pretium vulputate viverra. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
<input type="button" value="Change Background" ng-click="changeImage()"/>
</div>
```